# Remote Assistance Connection String 2

Tags: c#, rdp

I am working on an application where we are a network projector so we can let the user connect to us and we will get their screen via rdp.  We have written our own version of an RDP app and it works very well.  On Network Projector I have made it so all the SOAP messages are being received and sent out correctly.  The one issue I am having is that I get a remote assistance ticket, Remote Assistance Connection String 2, below is an example of the ticket I get:

```
<CRPInvitation Version='1.0' Secured='true'>
    <SecurityProtocol>Password</SecurityProtocol>
    <Ticket>&lt;E&gt;&lt;A KH=&quot;2lcmM4/Lk/SWK+EKwPxNdMkNJAE=&quot; ID=&quot;Ru3Bb9tDnJxIHZi0BnTcp/DoI7o8HjUpMsSby5NcvcFyibuZx0CElKvYsfEt3l5I&quot;/&gt;&lt;C&gt;&lt;T ID=&quot;1&quot; SID=&quot;0&quot;&gt;&lt;L P=&quot;5363&quot; N=&quot;fe80::bd44:89c6:855b:b231%22&quot;/&gt;&lt;L P=&quot;5363&quot; N=&quot;10.10.31.15&quot;/&gt;&lt;/T&gt;&lt;/C&gt;&lt;/E&gt;</Ticket>
    <Signature>6aff15e6a4dd1ccefa17be00bdf1aac6c34387bed2397ff3501bcf26b963fede</Signature>
    <Resolution Width='1280' Height='800' ColorDepth='32'/>
</CRPInvitation>
```

I am curious if anyone can tell me what the KH is for and how to decrypt the ID part of the A node.  Here is a link to the MS documentation on this string but it does not give any information that is needed in order to use the ticket.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc240132.aspx

Comment: When you post code be sure to highlight it and click the button that looks like `{  }`, that will make sure things like the XML tags are not removed and not mess with formatting. I fixed it for you and fixed up the line breaks too.